# How can I reduce overdue requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I assign 30 requests for each site's topics. For some, 15-20 requests go in vain. How can I reduce this?

I am extracting data from a site using the Python BeautifulSoup library.

```
The architecture of the site is as follows ( each topic ):
      www.abc.com/
      www.abc.com/1
      www.abc.com/2
      www.abc.com/3
      www.abc.com/4
      www.abc.com/5
      www.abc.com/6
```

```py
for firstTemplate in firstTemplates:
      i=1
      while i < 30:
          sendRequest = requests.get(firstTemplate + str(i))
          source = BeautifulSoup(sendRequest.content, "lxml")
          i = i + 1
```

When I look at all the issues of the site, the average / number is 25-26. But not all threads are the same and I'm assigning 30 requests as fixed.

For example: [www.abc.com/5](http://www.abc.com/5) after 30 requests. I'm throwing 25 request for nothing.

Should I write something like, "pull the same data out of the loop"? I think this will improve the performance of the program. But I don't know how.

Comment: there’s no threads here, why not check to see if you return anything from your request and then break the loop if it doesn’t

Comment: @aws_apprentice For example : www.abc.com/7 I can throw max 7 to this site, right? But when it throws 8, it directs to www.abc.com

Comment: i have no idea how many requests you can throw at the site, but clearly after you reach a max it will either return nothing or something completely different, so just check for that condition